# What's wrong with my Magento coupon?

Tags: magento, logic, coupon, promotion-code

I'm tasked with creating a coupon code in Magento that will do the following:

- if the customer purchases one bin (GCO350), one box from a category of items (box a), and one box from a different category of items (box b), they get three free items from yet another category of items (prize).

Here's my logic (conditions and actions) with (hopefully) helpful annotation: 
[image: Conditions]
[image: Actions]

What am I missing here? I've tried these as categories as well, in this example I literally selected every SKU that is applicable. :( Mage Wizards, help me out!

Comment: I did not understand: customer has to add 3 free items to the cart together with regular products or you want to add prizes automatically?

Comment: No, customers need to buy three different items (bin, box a and box b - where box a and box b are different categories of product) and in order to get three of the "prizes" (promotional item) for free. I realize it sounds a bit strange, but when it comes to the product I work with it makes sense. You can see the solution (as far as I can see so far) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It appears that you need to separate each category out into its own line in order for Magento to consider them all separately, so the answer is:

[image: Fixed it]

Silly mistake.